# unable to select "CUSTOM" profile preset in edit mode for specific edge in python script

Tags: python, bevel

I want to select 'Custom' profile preset for specific edge of a mesh object. I tried with bevel modifier where I can access preset via script but there I can not select specific edge instead it beveled the whole mesh. I looked through documentation but there is no preset option only profile type option. Is there any way to select specific edge using bevel modifier with custom profile preset option enabled?

bpy.ops.mesh.bevel(offset_type='OFFSET', offset=0.0, ***profile_type***='SUPERELLIPSE', offset_pct=0.0, segments=1, profile=0.5, affect='EDGES', clamp_overlap=False, loop_slide=True, mark_seam=False, mark_sharp=False, material=- 1, harden_normals=False, face_strength_mode='NONE', miter_outer='SHARP', miter_inner='SHARP', spread=0.1, vmesh_method='ADJ', release_confirm=False)

In order to clear confusions, I'm talking about the red mark option which clearly written as preset in blender UI.

[image]

Comment: I did not find related questions. If exists requested to share a link.

Comment: I think you might not understand what 'preset' means in Blender.  When you set the `profile_type` to "CUSTOM", you are selecting the custom profile option.  There is no custom profile _preset_ option.  A preset is just a collection of settings for the modifier.  When you use the dropdown menu to select a preset, you will see the settings change to match the preset.  So, as I said in the comment to my answer, you have two questions here: 1) How to set the settings from a preset, which you haven't asked, and 2) How to select specific edges, which I've answered.

Comment: I suggest you leave this question be about selecting edges and ask a separate selection about how to use presets to change settings.